# Is there a way I can make the GUI.label font bigger in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I am currently working on a 3d platformer and I have added a score system via script. The problem is that I have no idea how to change the font or change the size of the font. As a result, I can barely see the score. Is there any way I can change the color too?

Here is my script:

```
GUI.Label(new Rect(630, 20, 300, 100), "Score: " + points);
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: [Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.Label.html) says there is an overload for the Label method that takes a GUIStyle object. Via that class you can change almost anything here like font etc.

Comment: Does `GUI.Label()` return a Label class? Does that class have a Font or Style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GUIStyle s = new GUIStyle();
s.fontSize = 20;        
GUI.Label(new Rect(630, 20, 300, 100), "Score: " + points,s);
```

Comment: instead of using a new default style you should probably rather go through [new GUIStyle(`GUI.skin`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI-skin.html)[`.label)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUISkin-label.html) which is the default style for GUI.Label

Comment: It worked! tysm!